# Is there a possibility to pass .env file which is hosted on AWS S3 to docker compose when deploying on ECS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am just trying to deploy my application with docker compose to AWS ECS Fargate, is there a possibility to somehow reference that my env file is located on S3? AWS said it is possible, but in my experiments, it's turned out that is not.

Here are my templates on what I have tried yet.

```
some_service:
    image: ${ECR_IMAGE}
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
    env_file:
      - value: arn:aws:s3:::project-bucket/.env
        type: s3
```

```
some_service:
    image: ${ECR_IMAGE}
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
    environmentFiles:
      - value: arn:aws:s3:::project-bucket/.env
        type: s3
```

```
some_service:
    image: ${ECR_IMAGE}
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
    env_file: arn:aws:s3:::project-bucket/.env
```

Here is a link to docs what I has read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html

--- Solution

Here is the solution, you need to use `x-aws-cloudformation`:

```
x-aws-cloudformation:
  Resources:
    AppTaskDefinition:
      Properties:
        ContainerDefinitions:
          - Image: ${ECR_IMAGE}
            Name: ${APP_NAME}
            environmentFiles:
              - value: arn:aws:s3:::project-bucket/.env
                type: s3
    AppTaskExecutionRole:
      Properties:
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: S3ReadEnvAccess
            PolicyDocument: |
              {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                  {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                      "s3:GetObject"
                    ],
                    "Resource": [
                      "arn:aws:s3:::project-bucket/*"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                      "s3:GetBucketLocation"
                    ],
                    "Resource": [
                      "arn:aws:s3:::project-bucket"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
```

Comment: I don't think that's directly supported by `docker-compose`. You would need to look at the CloudFormation template being generated by the docker-compose ECS plugin: https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/#tuning-the-cloudformation-template and possibly provide an override setting in there.